# Objectify filter does not work except for fetch by id

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Initially my task was to filter the records by date for which I wrote the below query that returned no result even though I have 4 records in data store that meets the condition

```java
    ObjectifyService.run(() -> ObjectifyService.ofy().cache(false).load().type(SomeClass.class).filter("createdDate <", date.toString())
                .list());
```

Note - I have the index for createdDate.

Later, Just wanted to check whether it is really fetching things, I wrote fetch all records which returns no results

```java
    ObjectifyService.run(() -> ObjectifyService.ofy().cache(false).load().type(SomeClass.class).list());
```

I have a method that queries on id and right now only that works.

```java
    ObjectifyService.run(() -> ObjectifyService.ofy().cache(false).load().type(SomeClass.class).id("someId").now());
```

Can't figure what's the issue here.

Below is the Entity itself

```java
    @Entity(name = "SomeClass")
    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Subclass
    public class SomeClass implements Serializable {

        @Id
        private String id;
        private int importId;
        private String name;
        private String value;
        private Date lastModified;
        @Index
        private Date createdDate;
        private List<SomeOtherClass> someOtherClass;

    }
```

I feel this has something to do with @subclass annotation. Is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
filter("createdDate <", date.toString())
```

You're filtering a date field by a string value. Date fields must be filtered by date values. Drop the `toString()` and you should see expected behavior.

The schemaless nature of the datastore means you don't get typechecking errors when comparing values of different types. In fact, you could save some entities with the field as String and some entities with the field as Date (generally though it's a bad idea). The datastore has an absolute ordering; all Strings (no matter their content) are larger than all Dates, so your filter returns nothing.

Comment: Still no results. I changed it to date and it still the same. I am more intrigued about the query where there is no filter. Even that is not returning me any results. I am stuck here.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you re: the nonfiltered query. Are you trying this immediately after creating an entity? Perhaps you are seeing eventually consistent results. Is this in prod, in the dev instance, or in the test harness?

Comment: Basically, I have a scheduler that runs to clean up the datastore. When scheduler runs, it doesn't run immediately after entity creation. This is in dev instance.

Also, Is it possible to query the subclass entity directly without querying base class and then reaching to subclass entites?

Comment: There's something confuddled here. You want either the `@Entity` annotation or the `@Subclass` annotation, never both. And if you're filtering by the subclass, make sure you index it `@Subclass(index=true)`

Comment: True. Taking away the @Entity annotation solved it. Thanks :)